# Use of repeated type with Symfony

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

for one property of my object (newPSW), I use a repeated type in the form builder.

```
$builder->add('NewPSW', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'blablabla',
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'New password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Confirm password'),
            ))
        ));
```

if I look at the code source the name of the two fields are newPSW[first] and newPSW[second]

Validating my form, I would like to add a custom error to NewPSW property.
For any other "normal" field, I would do this (and it works good) :

```
$error = new FormError("What I want to say");
$form->get('object Property name')->addError($error);
```

I tried to do the same thing with this field but the error message does not display.

Q1 What do I have to write in the 'get' method of the $form to add the error?

I tried this already :

```
$form->get('newPSW')->addError($error); (no error but nothing is displayed)
$form->get('newPSW[first]')->addError($error); (error : Child "newPSW[first]" does not exist)
```

Comment: It's not a direct answer but would it not be possible to use Assert annotation for validation and custom error messages in the entity?

Comment: @SOGARA : ok knowing that I cannot touch the twig part, is it possible to do anything to change the behaviour of this type ?

Comment: @SOGARA: By the way, why the validation with the annotation show the errors near the field.. It is just when I add and error like shown up there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide custom error message for the second of the repeated field like this:

```
$form->get('NewPSW')->get('second')->addError(new FormError('Oops! This is error message for confirm field'));
```

Comment: Thank you... this is exactly this